# Navigate to SQLite object related to an other object, fetched from the database

Tags: c#, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm trying to navigate to an object, related to an other object.

In this situation, there are 2 classes; **StockTakeSession** and **Location**. These 2 have a one-to-one relation. When there are 2 objects created of each class and I set the relation as in the code below. I can navigate through it as I like without any issues. **But** when I fetch a StockTakeSession from the database, only LocationId has a value, and Location itself is null. To solve this, I created the extended get method for StockTakeSession.Location.

I'm quite new with C#/SQLite/ORM, so I was wondering if this is just how it is suppose to work or do I need to use a different approach?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Robert

---

These are the 2 Classes:

```
// These are the Stock Take Sessions
public class StockTakeSession : DomainModels
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    // One to many relationship with StockItems
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; }


    // Specify the foreign key to Location
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    // One to one relationship with Location

    private Location location;

    [OneToOne]
    public Location Location
    {


        get
        {
            if (location == null)
            {
                DataBase db = new DataBase();

                Location locationTemp = db.SelectLocation(LocationId);

                return locationTemp;
            }
            else
                return location;

        }

        set
        {
            location = value;
        }
    }
}

// These are the Locations where the Stock Take Sessions are done
public class Location : DomainModels, IComparable<Location>
{
    [JsonProperty("id"), PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return Name + " - (" + Postcode + ")";
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Location other)
    {
        return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }

    // Navigation property
    // One to many relationship with StockItems
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All), Ignore]
    public List<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; }

    // Specify the foreign key to StockTakeSession
    [ForeignKey(typeof(StockTakeSession))]
    public int StockTakeSessionId { get; set; }

    // One to one relationship with StockTakeSession
    [OneToOne]
    public StockTakeSession StockTakeSession { get; set; }

}
```

How I store the relation between to objects:

```
StockTakeSession newSession = new StockTakeSession
{
    LocationId = selectedLocation.Id,
    Location = selectedLocation,
    DateTime = DateTime.Now

};

db.Insert(newSession, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sqlite-net-extensions, relationships are not loaded on demand. You have to fetch them from Database when you need them.

Change your implementation for `Location` to a simple getter/setter.

```
[OneToOne]
public Location Location { get; set; }
```

Then, load the session relationships when you need it:

```
db.GetChildren(session);
```

For example:

```
db.GetWithChildren<StockTakeSession>(stockId);
```

Will fetch the `StockTakeSession` object with that Id and also load relationships and set the inverse relationships.